# Should I use WebSocket for this use case

Tags: javascript, websocket

I kind of new for WebSocket and would like to ask you guys a question if WebSocket is really the best way I should go.

Use case. Clients need to submit different kinds of jobs, e.g. J1, J2, J3, ... to server API through web GUI and the server will do or distribute to other computational resources to accomplish the jobs, however the server needs to update each Client the progress of the jobs they submit. One very simple example is that, if Client A wants to upload a big file, and server needs to notify the progress of the uploading until it is fully uploaded. I do think this is a very common use case.

The way I am doing now is to use HTTP polling, i.e. query status from Client side every 1s to get status from the server and display. I do think there must be other more efficient way of doing this, and I come up with WebSocket way. However after doing some reading, WebSocket's best use is to real-time broadcast same data to all subscripters, e.g. updating a certain stock price in a given channel.

Do you guys think if WebSocket is the right way to go? if so, how should I build the channel for different Clients and different types of jobs,  or any other suggestions?

thank you.

Comment: _"WebSocket's best use is to real-time broadcast same data to all subscripters"_ What gave you that impression?  You can use individual sockets to send whatever data you want - this very website uses them to provide various individual updates (eg rep changes, vote changes on questions you're looking at etc), and (I believe) have in the order of 500,000 concurrent connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSocket may be a solution if you require real-time notification. You don't need different channels for each job, you just need messages that allow you to multiplex on server-side and demultiplex on client-side.

You should take into account that each opened WebSocket uses resources on the server, so you should consider the average workload.

On the other hand, if you don't require real-time notifications, loose polling may be a better solution.